# Zend project hosting session issues

Tags: php, session, zend-framework

I'm hosting a Zend project in the server. After solving some .htaccess problems now I'm facing session issues.

this is the error i see :

> exception 'Zend_Session_Exception' with message 'Zend_Session::start() - /home/*****/public_html/***/***/library/Zend/Session.php(Line:477): Error #2 session_start() [function.session-start]: open(/tmp/sci/sess_0c949aecb59cfcaa46f46dd45ab9313a, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) /home/*****/public_html/***/***/library/Zend/Session.php(Line:487): Error #2 session_write_close()

/tmp/sci/ is an existing folder but i can't see any session file inside it. It seems to me, that Zend is trying to look for a session file form a session id which is not already created.

Help much appreciated.

Comment: Is `/tmp/sci` writable for the process?

Comment: it has 755 as permissions

Comment: `755` doesn't answer my question. It says The owner of that directory is allowed to write here. Is that process the owner?

Comment: ok, for testing purpose i changed it to 777. but i still get the same error.